# Printing website scrape loop directly into Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, beautifulsoup, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm scraping a bunch of website data and am able to print to terminal, but having real trouble pushing it directly to a sheet.

I can confirm Gspread connection is working - my code loops through the names, but doesn't touch the sheet.

I thought the last line of code (append) would place the results.

Ultimately, I just want to full result of my code in columns on the sheet, but having trouble.

If there's a better approach would love any guidance:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TD4YmhfAsnSL_Fwo1lckEbnUVBQB6VyKC05ieJ7PKCw/edit#gid=0

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1TD4YmhfAsnSL_Fwo1lckEbnUVBQB6VyKC05ieJ7PKCw')
worksheet = sh.sheet1
# AddValue = ["Test", 25, "Test2"]
# worksheet.insert_row(AddValue, 3)


def get_links(url):
    data = []
    req_url = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req_url.content, "html.parser")

    for td in soup.find_all('td', {'data-th': 'Player'}):
        a_tag = td.a
        name = a_tag.text
        player_url = a_tag['href']
        print(f"Getting {name}")

        req_player_url = requests.get(
            f"https://basketball.realgm.com{player_url}")
        soup_player = BeautifulSoup(req_player_url.content, "html.parser")
        div_profile_box = soup_player.find("div", class_="profile-box")
        row = {"Name": name, "URL": player_url}

        for p in div_profile_box.find_all("p"):
            try:
                key, value = p.get_text(strip=True).split(':', 1)
                row[key.strip()] = value.strip()
            except:     # not all entries have values
                pass

        data.append(row)

    return data


urls = [
    'https://basketball.realgm.com/dleague/players/2022',
]


for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)

    for entry in data:
        worksheet.append_row(entry)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I thought that `data` of `data = get_links(url)` is an array including JSON object. In the current stage, `append_row` cannot directly use the JSON object. I thought that this is the reason for your current issue.
- In your script, `append_row` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)

    for entry in data:
        worksheet.append_row(entry)
```

#### To:

```
res = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Getting: {url}")
    data = get_links(url)
    res = [*res, *data]

if res != []:
    header = list(res[0].keys())
    values = [header, *[[e[k] if e.get(k) else "" for k in header] for e in res]]
    worksheet.append_rows(values, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- In this modification, all values are retrieved in the for a loop. And, the retrieved values are put into the Spreadsheet by one API call with `append_rows`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, the header row is used with `header = list(res[0].keys())`. If you want to use your expected ordered headers, please manually put it to `header = list(res[0].keys())`.

#### Reference:

- [append_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/api/models/worksheet.html#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_rows)

Comment: amazing solution.  I see, this is super helpful in my learning.  These past 6 months I've learned an insane amount and it's because of people like you.  Thank you!

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.